# Is there a way to disable Ctlr+Z (or "undo") in a specific sheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that creates an additional sheet in my file called "Changelog" which tracks changes from another sheet (but same file) called "Source". It appends a new row with information specified in the script, however, if I were to undo something in the source sheet, it also undoes and removes the appended row in the Changelog sheet, which is not the ideal behavior.

Is there a way to disable Ctrl+Z in just my Changelog sheet? Or should I just make my script create a separate Google Sheet file altogether and make that my Changelog? I'm trying to avoid the latter because I want to have that information easily accessible to the users using the source file without having to refer to two separate files. Protecting the sheet also does not make it immune to when I undo something in the source file.

Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to disable feature like `Undo`.

Spreadsheet is not a good instrument to use it as a add-only log. If you already logging events through Google Apps Script, I recommend you to use `console.log(...)` instead, because it is faster than SpreadSheet updating and data is logged to [Logging service](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/).

It can contain much more data and it can filter and search faster.

Resources:

- [Class `console` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console)

Comment: Well the idea is to eventually use the Changelog sheet to import into ChartIO and it would be sort of our "events" table. Is that possible using the logging service?